# SSRS Report Behavior Stuck in IE 11 only

Tags: internet-explorer, reporting-services, internet-explorer-11, ssrs-2012

While loading SSRS report, it works fine in IE10,IE9, Firefox and in chrome as well.

But not showing perfect in IE11 only.

While opening by Document Mode - 10 or 9 it shows scroll bar and full report in single page but in IE 11 it shows data outside the page. Please check below image.

[image]

Please help me!

Comment: your picture is a bit unclear. Can you  explain what should be shown vs what is incorrectly shown?

Comment: actually the issue is, when I load the report in IE browser data not coming inside report viewer - after some height it always showing outside the report viewer page. it works perfectly fine in Chrome as well as in Firefox. Even I try to check the same in IE9 and IE10 it works fine. issue with IE11 only. what should I do? please help